# Typescript automaticaly add ~/ instead of ../../ on VSCode imports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, babeljs

Let's say I have a React Native application.
I am working on a component like this:

```
import { AppText } from '~/components/common/primitives/app-text'

<AppText>Hello friend</AppText>
```

I use successfully `babel-plugin-root-import` with `module-resolver`.
Everything works like a charm.

My problem is when I use the VSCode shortcut with `cmd` + `.` to automatically import the dependencies typescript (or VSCode?) decide to import with `../../`

```
import { AppText } from '../../common/primitives/app-text'

<AppText>Hello friend</AppText>
```

[image]

#### Question:

How can I let VSCode or typescript automatically import with `~/component` instead of `../../` when I use the auto-import shortcut?

---

*Update*:

After looking at another project and tried to delete the `tsconfig.json`,
I can reproduce the issue.

When I copy this config it's working again on project 2.

```js
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

[image: import with ~on VScode]

The problem still happens on project 1, What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to change your `.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I **rebooted my machine** and it's working now 
Probably it was a weird cache issue

[image]